# string extraction in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to eliminate part of a string in R. The string is as follows

"ENSG00000003137 |2 |CYP26B1 |72356367 |72359355"

I want the resultant string to be

"|2 |CYP26B1 |72356367 |72359355"

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
  substr(s, regexpr("\\|", s), nchar(s))
  #  [1] "|2 |CYP26B1 |72356367 |72359355"
```

Where `s` is your string

---

(a) `regexpr` finds the occurrence of the first `|` in your string.
(b) `nchar` counts the total length (in characters) of your string
    `substr` then takes a substring from (a) to (b)

Comment: @user2498657 then you should accept his answer...